# How to assert that a method is called in my Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-strap

I have this snippet of code in a directive

```
var modalPromise = $modal({template: '/Templates/Alerts/Upsell.html', persist: true, show: false, backdrop: 'static', scope: scope});
                                $q.when(modalPromise).then(function(modalEl) {
                                    modalEl.modal('show');
                                });
```

In my Jasmine test I want to assert that the `show` method is called, so I have this

```
...

.service('modal', function () { 
              var $modal = jasmine.createSpyObj('$modal', ['show']);
              return $modal;
          })

...

expect($modal('show')).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But this gives me the error `Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined.`

I think I am doing something wrong here.  How do I assert that this line is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plunker or fiddle would have helped here but here is my assumption. After spying the `$modal` for `show` you also have to call `andCallThrough()` to allow all subsequent calls to be delegated to actual implementation of `$modal`. Like:

```
.service('modal', function () { 
    var modal;
    spyOn(modal, 'show').andCallThrough();

    return modal;
})
```

Comment: This did not work but here's a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4JfktR1slEAadtgYMs7G?p=preview.  Let me know if you need other things included in the Plunker.